# getServiceLocator only works with LoginController

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entitymanager

I am using ZF2 with Doctrine 2 ORM, using the following:

```
$objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
```

seems to work in `LoginController` but doesn't seem to work in any other controller, what might be the reasons ? ( All controllers are under the same application )

```
<?php

namespace OEC;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{


    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig(){
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){

            $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
            $controller      = $e->getTarget();


                if ($controller instanceof Controller\LoginController) {
                    $controller->layout('login/login.phtml');
                } else {
                    $controller->layout('layout/layout.phtml');
                }
        }, 100);
    }

    public function getServiceConfig(){
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => function($serviceManager) {
                    return $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
                }
            )
        );
    }


}

?>
```

Constantly getting this error Call to a member function get() on null

My working controller

```
<?php

namespace OEC\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use OEC\Controller\CommonController;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function indexAction(){

        $session = self::checkUserLoginAction();

        if( $session ){
            return $this->redirect()->toUrl( MAIN_URL . 'oec/view/dashboard');
        }

        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function loginAction(){


        $username = $this->getRequest()->getPost('username');
        $password = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');

        try{
            $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

            $user = $objectManager->getRepository('OEC\Entity\User')->findOneBy(array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)  ));

            if( !$user ){
                print_r("not found");exit;
            }

            if( $user && $user->getId() != 0 ){

                $session = new Container('user');
                $session->userId = $user->getId();
                $session->username = $user->getUsername();
                $session->userType = $user->getUserTypeId();

                CommonController::json(true, "successfully logged in", NULL, "view/dashboard");exit;

            }

        }catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            print_r("error");exit;
        }

    }


    public static function checkUserLoginAction(){

        $session = new Container('user');

        if( $session->offsetExists('username') && $session->offsetExists('userId') && $session->offsetExists('userType') ){

            return array(
              "username" => $session->offsetGet('username'),
              "name" => $session->offsetGet('name'),
              "userType" => $session->offsetGet('userType')
            );

        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function logoutAction(){

        $session = new Container('user');
        $session->getManager()->destroy();

        return $this->redirect()->toUrl( MAIN_URL . 'oec/view/login');

    }

}
```

My not working controller

```
<?php
namespace OEC\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class BloodTypeController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function listAll(){

        $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine');

        $bloodRep = $objectManager->getRepository('OEC\Entity\Blood');
        $bloods = $bloodRep->findAll();

        $bloodsArr = array();

        foreach( $bloods as $blood ){

            array_push($bloodsArr , $blood->toArray() );
        }

        $objectManager->close();

        return $bloods;
    }
}
```

Comment: how many modules do you have? and post your `modules.config.php` too for module that you are trying to work on for the moment

Comment: @noobie-php I have 2 modules

Comment: You said the call doesn't work from your controllers, but the code you've included in your question is of a module class. Please edit your question to include an example of the relevant controller code that doesn't work.

Comment: @TimFountain I added them

Comment: Not sure why you're calling get `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` in one controller and get `doctrine` in another (this may be valid - I don't use Doctrine). Are you sure that the error is coming from the `listAll()` action in the problem controller code? A full stack trace of the error might be useful.

Comment: yes, apparently when I call the listAll function let say from a route it works just fine, but inner calls from a function to another is making this issue happen

Comment: What exactly are the error logs saying? And unless you added it as alias at some point the Doctrine EntityManager isn't registered under 'doctrine'.

Comment: Is there a way to create or define an entityManager of doctrine without using the ServiceLocator ? @netiul

Comment: There is a way, yes, but you really don't want to do this. Have you defined a factory for `BloodyTypeController`?

Comment: yes I did ... I edited the code above for my module.config.php and Module.php

Comment: Could you add the factory code for `BloodTypeController`?

Comment: If you don't set the service manager to your controller in this factory, you might need to. Although `get('doctrine')` is wrong, the error was thrown because `get` was called on `NULL` which means your controller doesn't have a service manager at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "inner calls from a function to another"? You've said that the listAll action in your question works fine when called from a route, so once again, please provide an example of the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`doctrine` is not a valid name to get an entity manager, there are two ways to get it directly through the service manager:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get("Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager");
```

as you did in your `LoginController` will trigger the standard factory and always returns the entity manager `orm_default`

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get("doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default");
```

will trigger an abstract factory and returns the entity manager `orm_default` or a different entity manager if you replace `orm_default` after the last dot. This is the most common way to get the entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

You use 3 different ways to get your service (the `EntityManager` instance):

```
$serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
$objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine');
```

This third one is wrong. You are getting the `Doctrine` service, to get the `EntityManager` instance you need to call an additional `->getEntityManager();`

```
$objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
```

This `'doctrine'` service is typically available in **Symfony framework** and does **not work in Zend Framework 2**

If would suggest to consistently use one service name:

```
$objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
```

This should work.

---

### Another solution

Another even better solution is to make your controller dependent on the `ObjectManager`, use [the doctrine `ObjectManagerAwareInterface`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Persistence/ObjectManagerAwareInterface.php) inside the Controller class and inject the service in a factory.

To do this you need to register your controller in the `module.config.php` under `controllers` - `factories` like this:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'OEC\Controller\BloodTypeController' => 'OEC\Controller\Factory\BloodTypeControllerFactory'
    )
)
```

And then create a `BloodTypeControllerFactory`  factory class like this:

```
<?php
namespace OEC\Controller\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use OEC\Controller\BloodTypeController;

class BloodTypeControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return BloodTypeController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $controllerPluginManager = $serviceLocator;
        $serviceManager = $controllerPluginManager->get('ServiceManager');
        $objectManager = $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        return new BloodTypeController($objectManager);
    }
}
```

And then add following to your `OEC\Controller\BloodTypeController`:

```
<?php
namespace OEC\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class BloodTypeController extends AbstractActionController implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager){
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager
    }

    /**
     * Set the object manager
     *
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     */
    public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get the object manager
     *
     * @return ObjectManager
     */
    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->objectManager();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function listAll()
    {
        $objectManager = $this->getObjectManager();

        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the possibility with `doctrine`? I got this exception message when I did: `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine` (using doctrine-orm-module 0.9.*)

Comment: @StoryTeller I added example for injecting the `ObjectManager` through a factory. What line returns this error? Are you sure it is the line in the controller class?

Comment: @StoryTeller I think this `get('doctrine')` is typically for Symfony framework. This doesn't work for Zend Framework 2

Comment: I got this error Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to OEC\Controller\BloodTypeController::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given,

Comment: @f0unix Did you register your factory? Where is this error thrown?